FreeIPA ldap GSSAPI mechanism no longer works for Kerberos
I upgraded my FreeIPA server on Rocky 9 and the GSSAPI mechanism for Kerberos no longer works. I'm getting error 49, invalid credentials.
In the /var/log/sssd/sssd_caps.int.log it shows:
   *  (2024-07-08 17:39:22): [be[caps.int]] [sasl_bind_send] (0x0100): [RID#1508] Executing sasl bind mech: GSSAPI, user: host/pacific.caps.int
   *  (2024-07-08 17:39:23): [be[caps.int]] [sasl_bind_send] (0x0020): [RID#1508] ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s failed (49)[Invalid credentials]

Running ldapsearch -x works but using GSSAPI does not work:
root@pacific ~ $ kinit adminipa
root@pacific ~ $ ldapsearch -LLL -Y GSSAPI -s "base" -b "" supportedSASLMechanisms
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
root@pacific ~ $ klist
Ticket cache: KCM:0:6383
Default principal: adminipa@CAPS.INT

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/08/2024 23:24:53  07/09/2024 23:09:02  krbtgt/CAPS.INT@CAPS.INT
07/08/2024 23:25:11  07/09/2024 23:09:02  HTTP/pacific.caps.int@CAPS.INT
07/08/2024 23:40:03  07/09/2024 23:09:02  ldap/pacific.caps.int@CAPS.INT

Here is the ldap config, /etc/openldap/ldap.conf:
SASL_NOCANON    on
BASE dc=caps,dc=int
TLS_CACERT /etc/ipa/ca.crt
SASL_MECH GSSAPI
URI ldaps://pacific.caps.int

The krb5 config file, /etc/krb5.conf:
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = CAPS.INT
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 rdns = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = true
 udp_preference_limit = 0
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 CAPS.INT = {
  kdc = pacific.caps.int:88
  master_kdc = pacific.caps.int:88
  kpasswd_server = pacific.caps.int:464
  admin_server = pacific.caps.int:749
  default_domain = caps.int
  pkinit_anchors = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/kdc-ca-bundle.pem
  pkinit_pool = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/ca-bundle.pem
}

[domain_realm]
 .caps.int = CAPS.INT
 caps.int = CAPS.INT
 pacific.caps.int = CAPS.INT

[dbmodules]
  CAPS.INT = {
    db_library = ipadb.so
  }

[plugins]
 certauth = {
  module = ipakdb:kdb/ipadb.so
  enable_only = ipakdb
 }

/etc/krb5.conf.d/freeipa-server:
[plugins]
    certauth = {
        module = ipakdb:kdb/ipadb.so
        enable_only = ipakdb
    }
    kdcpolicy = {
        module = ipakdb:kdb/ipadb.so
        enable_only = ipakdb
    }

/etc/krb5.conf.d/freeipa:
[libdefaults]
    spake_preauth_groups = edwards25519

Ipa upgraded from 4.10.0-8 to 4.11.0-15. The firewall is not the issue. I'm at a loss.

Is FIPS mode enabled? Im getting similar errors due to that.
